# Difference between "a:active" and ".active a.class"

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have in a css file this:

```
#toolbar a.opener:hover,
#toolbar a.opener:active,
#toolbar a.opener:focus {
    something1;
}
#toolbar .active a.opener {
    something2;
}
```

**Questions**:

1. What is the difference between the "first active" and the "second
   active"?
2. When are called the "first active" and the "second active"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first rule incorporates "pseudo" classes, which target the element when it's in a certain state.  The :active pseudo-selector applies to the element when the user is clicking on it.

The latter rule is simply a class selector, which applies to an anchor element which has the class "opener" and is a descendand of an element which has the class "active".

Answer (score 7):

`:active` specifies the state in which an element is in. An element is `:active` when it is clicked on or gains focus through other means.

`.active` refers to a class name. In this case, the CSS rule applies to an element that has the `active` class within the `#toolbar` parent element.

Answer (score 2):

The first `:active` (the colon matters) refers to the `active` [pseudo css class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) which is automatically set by the browser. The second `.active` refers to a simple css class that you (or your program) need to apply to the element.

So to answer your second question, the first one is applied automatically by the browser as soon as a user has clicked (activated) a link on your webpage, whereas the second one is never applied automatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
#toolbar a.opener:hover,
#toolbar a.opener:active,
#toolbar a.opener:focus {
    something1;
}
```

applies in the

```
<div id="toolbar">
  <a class="opener"></a>
</div>
```

when in hover, active or focus state. While

```
#toolbar .active a.opener {
    something2;
}
```

applies in

```
<div id="toolbar"> 
  <div class="active">  
    <a class="opener"></a> 
  </div>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

These are `:pseudo` states:

```
#toolbar a.opener:hover,
#toolbar a.opener:active,
#toolbar a.opener:focus {
    something1;
}
```

This `.active` is a class that's been added to a parent of `a.opener`:

```
#toolbar .active a.opener {
    something2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

active is a state bw press and release of mouse button.

read ,

- [:active selector documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)
- [Another article](https://bitsofco.de/when-do-the-hover-focus-and-active-pseudo-classes-apply/)