# How to apply a:active pseudo class to my CSS code?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to add `a:active` pseudo-class to my .blurb_underline class that is applied on four different objects (blurbs). Basically, I want the underline to stick around after one of the blurbs is clicked (and also for one to be active on page load).

```
.blurb_underline h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.blurb_underline p {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.blurb_underline h4:hover {
  color: #e02b20;
}

.blurb_underline h4:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0s ease, background .5s ease;
}

.blurb_underline h4:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background: #e02b20;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.blurb_underline h4:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  background: #e02b20;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.blurb_underline h4:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0s ease;
}
```

Thank you kindly :)

Here is an image of the section:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCAtR.jpg

Comment: Can you add some HTML to make a working snippet? What are the elements inside a `blurb` element?

Comment: you can also add a screeschot or an image of what you aspect

Comment: _“I want the underline to stick around after one of the blurbs is clicked”_ - then you don’t want `:active`, because that applies only from the moment you press the mouse button down until you release it again. _“and also for one to be active on page load”_ - then you need to make that element discernible from the others, for example by adding a class `active`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993083/difference-between-aactive-and-active-a-class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `:active` pseudo-selector applies when the user is *currently* clicking on the element. That's not what you want to use.

If you want a style to be *maintained* “after one of the blurbs is clicked”, the easiest way is to add another class when you click on it, by using events in JavaScript.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
// Get all blurbs elements
var blurbs = document.getElementsByClassName("blurb_underline");

// Function to remove the “active” class from all blurbs
function blurbsDeactivate() {
  [].forEach.call(blurbs, function(blurb) {
    blurb.classList.remove("active");
  });
}

// Do the following for each blurb
[].forEach.call(blurbs, function(blurb) {
  // Do the following on click on any blurb
  blurb.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    blurbsDeactivate(); // Launch function to remove “active” on all blurbs
    this.classList.add("active"); // Add the “active” class on the one just clicked
  });
});
```

```css
.blurb_underline h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.blurb_underline p {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.blurb_underline h4:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0s ease, background .5s ease;
}

.blurb_underline h4:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background: #e02b20;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.blurb_underline h4:hover,
.blurb_underline.active h4 { /* Added this line */
  color: #e02b20;
}

.blurb_underline h4:hover:before,
.blurb_underline.active h4:before { /* Added this line */
  width: 100%;
  background: #e02b20;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.blurb_underline h4:hover:after,
.blurb_underline.active h4:after { /* Added this line */
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0s ease;
}

/* Added to enhance snippet */
.blurb_underline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurb_underline active"><!-- Start as active -->
  <h4>Blurb1 h4</h4>
  <p>Blurb1 p</p>
</div>
<div class="blurb_underline">
  <h4>Blurb2 h4</h4>
  <p>Blurb2 p</p>
</div>
<div class="blurb_underline">
  <h4>Blurb3 h4</h4>
  <p>Blurb3 p</p>
</div>
<div class="blurb_underline">
  <h4>Blurb4 h4</h4>
  <p>Blurb4 p</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Thomas As it alters the DOM, you can try putting this script just before the `</body>` closing tag. That ensures everything is loaded before executing it. If it doesn't work, well… I don't know why. There is already a lot of stuff and scripts.